# Android 4.0 emulator always has a crashing Launcher?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to make an Android 4.0 emulator. I've tried this process on a fairly fast computer in both Linux and Windows(Phenom II X6 w/ 8G of RAM) and every time I get "unfortunately, launcher has stopped" when I try to look at the menu of the launcher.

[image]

I have tried having the RAM size all the way up to 1024M, but nothing seems to help it. Is this just a borked emulator or what?

Comment: I updated VM Heap size 256 and stopped

Comment: As Balavishnu's answer suggests, it seems the default heap size (16) is too small. It is a pretty blatant bug that the emulated device doesn't work in its default configuration. Have you filed a bug with Google?

Comment: You don't need 1 GB RAM for your emulator for testing a single app! May be its a bug, I haven't filed that bug. If my answer helped you to some extend, please accept my ans.

Comment: Hi I was getting same error with 32 heap set it to 64 and worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 47):

I have experienced this same problem, several times. All I did was changed the RAM size to 512, and heap to 32. Rest all good...

@racs here suggested that changing the emulator skin in the AVD manager might also help. Give it a try...

Check if this helps.

Comment: Person that was experiencing this problem here. Can confirm that this fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Adjusting the memory setting wasn't working for me. However, when I changed the emulator skin in the AVD manager then suddenly these annoying pop-up errors disappeared at once.

Comment: Same here except that I went up to 1024 RAM and 64 HEAP

Comment: after changing the RAM size 512, and heap to 32. giving emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration. Whats next ? please advise.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also facing the same issue after updating latest SDK. I come up with following solution after spending few hours,

The problem is "unfortunately, launcher has stopped". This happens because of the AVD skin path not properly assigned in AVD's config.ini

For Ex. My AVD name is **AVD_4.0.3_WSVGA**

**before fix
skin.path=AVD_4.0.3_WSVGA**

so I changed skin path as follows,
**skin.path=platforms/android-15/skins/WSVGA**

you can find config.ini

in linux(Ubuntu) **/home/[username]/.android/avd/[your avd name]/config.ini**

Answer (score 4):

Try a different API level.

I got that idea [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/277542), and it worked a Nexus 7 AVD at API level 17 with an ARM CPU on OS X and it seems to be OK.

Comment: Change API level 17 or 18 and RAM size is 512 with heap size 64.. it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's solved for me When I change VM heap from 16 to 32

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK Manager & try it again, check this links [Adding SDK Components](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html)

Comment: I have just now (today) downloaded the 4.0 platform

Comment: Have you checked SDK Manger, is it showing all emulator installed successively?

Comment: All I need is the Platform right? (ARM-EABI system image is also installed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got "load from snapshot" on? if so you could try turning that off.

I also read here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/unfortunately-launcher-has-stopped-error-after-4-0-4-ota-upgrade were someone suggested clearing the launchers data in app settings.

Answer (score 0):

chage confing file in --> .android->avd->youavdfoldername->config
open file and change
hw.dPad=yes
hw.mainKeys=yes

Answer (score 0):

My solution was that you had to let the emulator boot up beforehand first.

To put it simply: the android emulator died from exhaustion when I tried to launch the app before the emulator had had time to boot up properly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers listed here helped me. I eventually fixed the problem by going to the advanced settings for my Virtual Device in Android Virtual Device Manager. My SD card was set to 9MB and it's recommended to set this to at least 10MB. When I set this to a higher value it fixed the problem. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by increasing the heap size to 128.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had to do factory reset on my phone twice to get rid of this. But I then realized that the issue always happened when I was testing one particular app and thus the prob was narrowed down. Also I saw the error file and it showed OOM crash lines.

I then checked my last changes within that application and I found out to my surprise that the custom app logo which I was using replacing ic_launcher was huge in size due to which everytime I ran that application System launcher tried opening it and ended up with OOM.

I know, I know it sounds weird but trust me this was the issue. I reduced the size and tested again and things were working fine.

Note - I even tried testing on my friend's phone and crashed his launcher too. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had also same problem, I resolved,now you should reset your adb,

1. open the emulator and Goto DDMS mode -->click next button of Screen Capture(Drop Down)-->Reset.adb.
   Or
2. Goto Run-->Cmd-->goto Path(platforms and tool in Android sdk)-->adb kill-server
   2.1 Goto Run-->Cmd-->goto Path(platforms and tool in Android sdk)-->adb start-server
   that's it,restart emulator am sure it will work..

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem before. The root cause of this issue is the RAM size. You cannot set the RAM size greater than 800MB.
In my case, in set the RAM size to 700MB and it works properly. So try to change you RAM size.

Comment: Tried everything mentioned here, still it crashes when using tablet 7 inch format.