# Nexus7 emulator crashing after creating it

Tags: android, crash, emulation, nexus-7

I am facing one more issue with the emulator.

First I faced the problem in creating emulator (Nexus 7) with the message

> emulator: Failed to open the HAX device! HAX is not working and
>   emulator runs in emulation mode emulator: Open HAX device failed
>   Failed to allocate memory: 8 This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the
>   application's support team for more information.

After following the instructions in of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/android-running-the-new-intel-emulator),  I able to create the nexus emulator.

After running the created emulator and tapping on menu it redirects to Menu screen (list of installed application on emulator), since it is a newly created and guide screen appears on the screen (see the screenshots), clicking on “OK” button the menu screen simply crashes with the message “unfortunately ,launcher has stopped”, check the below screens I have attached.

Let me know, if I can provide any more information regarding this to get it solved.

Note:  using Android SDK Tool – 21.0.1
[image: First screen]
[image: list of apps]
[image: crash]

Comment: I faced similar problem. looks like some bug. I can't even view in landscape mode. it just keeps on crashing. never used device definitions to create AVD's from then on.

Comment: @Santhosh- "it just keeps on crashing. never used device definitions to create AVD's" when did you faced the issue while creating the AVD or after launching the AVD?

Comment: After creating the AVD while using it. My Issue was exactly the same as you have described above.

Comment: I have post other solution [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16709138/781181

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to be a weird bug on Nexus 7 emulator. When you open the emulator, it shows opens drawer and shows "Choose some apps". There instead of pressing OK button, if you actually press and hold the Custom Locale icon it is showing and drop it to the main screen, the launcher stops crashing. It seems weird but when I did it, the crash stopped. This needs to be done the first time only. Then on, emulator opens normally.

Comment: Good one, it is working. Earlier I used the launch the activity from command line. Thank you.

Comment: +100 if i could.   What mental process lead you to discover this?

Comment: Haha frustration of getting the crash message for a few times when pressed OK button!!

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens because of the AVD skin path not properly assigned in AVD's config.ini

For Ex. My AVD name is **AVD_4.0.3_WSVGA**

before fix

**skin.path=AVD_4.0.3_WSVGA**

so I changed skin path as follows

**skin.path=platforms/android-15/skins/WSVGA**

you can find config.ini

in linux(Ubuntu) **/home/[username]/.android/avd/[you avd name]/config.ini**