# custom Android Virtual Device: System UI Stopped, Launcher Stopped

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I created an AVD with the properties below to emulate a customer's device. Each time I start it up, it gives the **"Unfortunately, System UI stopped"** dialog and, when dismissed, the **"Unfortunately, Launcher stopped."** dialog.
Tweaking the parameters (at least, those which don't alter the essential characteristics of the device) using advice from:

[Android emulator error: "System UI has stopped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678520/android-emulator-error-system-ui-has-stopped#16402304)

[Unfortunately System UI has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422275/unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Android 4.0 emulator always has a crashing Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155417/android-4-0-emulator-always-has-a-crashing-launcher)

https://daviddesmet.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/android-avd-unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped/

results in the same outcome.

Variations tried

- skin 320x320, 320x321
- Google API / non Google API
- heapsize 16, 32, 64, 128
- mainkeys yes, no
- keyboard yes, no
- ncore 1, 2, 4

I'm eventually going to borrow a device but hope to get a head start on things before the project start date so would be extremely grateful to hear of any workarounds other than those already attempted.

**config.ini**

```
Name: 3.0_Motorola_MC3200_API_16
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\me\.android\avd\3.0_Motorola_MC3200_API_16.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 16)
Skin: 320x320
SD Card: C:\Users\me\.android\avd\3.0_Motorola_MC3200_API_16.avd\sdcard.img
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: 3.0" Motorola MC3200
vm.heapSize: 128
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: User
hw.gps: no
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
skin.path.backup: _no_skin
image.androidVersion.api: 16
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-16\google_apis\x86\
hw.keyboard.lid: yes
tag.id: google_apis
showDeviceFrame: no
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: yes
AvdId: 3.0_Motorola_MC3200_API_16
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 160
avd.ini.displayname: 3.0  Motorola MC3200 API 16
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:799ea57969b556677321dbf45a563939
hw.ramSize: 1024
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: no
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: no
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

**Logcat extract: System UI stopped**

```
    01-23 12:31:05.364 1401-1453/system_process D/Tethering: MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
    01-23 12:31:11.584 1401-1414/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{aedb9d20 

    com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
    01-23 12:31:11.724 1401-1414/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    01-23 12:31:12.234 1401-1414/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{aedbcc68 

    com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
    01-23 12:31:21.514 1401-1415/system_process W/ActivityManager: Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{aedd3bc8 com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService}
    01-23 12:31:21.514 1401-1415/system_process I/ActivityManager: Crashing app skipping ANR: ProcessRecord{aedd43e8 1462:com.android.systemui/u0a35} 

Executing service com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
    01-23 12:31:21.584 1401-1414/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{aedb9d20 

    com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
    01-23 12:31:31.704 1158-1584/? I/SurfaceFlinger: Boot is finished (31860 ms)
    01-23 12:31:31.704 1401-1434/system_process W/WindowManager: ***** BOOT TIMEOUT: forcing display enabled
    01-23 12:31:41.574 1401-1489/system_process E/ThrottleService: problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: 

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**Logcat extract: Launcher Stopped**

```
 01-23 12:29:01.332 1407-1527/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.launcher for activity 

    com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: pid=1793 uid=10019 gids={1028}
    01-23 12:29:01.342 1793-1793/com.android.launcher E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
    01-23 12:29:01.352 1793-1793/com.android.launcher I/ActivityThread: Pub com.android.launcher2.settings: com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider
    01-23 12:29:01.372 1793-1793/com.android.launcher W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f03000d (t=2 e=13) in package 0 (error -75)
    01-23 12:29:01.372 1793-1793/com.android.launcher D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-23 12:29:01.372 1793-1793/com.android.launcher W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xae6de228)
    01-23 12:29:01.372 1793-1793/com.android.launcher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

    {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03000d
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03000d
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView

(PhoneWindow.java:256)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
                                                                            at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:361)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    01-23 12:29:01.392 1793-1795/com.android.launcher D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 6% free 6147K/6535K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 14ms
    01-23 12:29:01.392 1407-1590/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
```

**Environment**

- Android Studio 2.2.3
- Windows 7 x64

**Updates**
I have removed and reinstalled SDK and Android Studio.
I am able to replicate this on 2 development machines (so far) so would be useful to discover if anyone else experiences this behaviour for this config.

Comment: This is serious enough that I would first try completely uninstalling Android Studio and the SDK then starting over from scratch.

Comment: better to use genymotion emulator rather than to use android emulator

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Thanks, and agreed. I have already done this and should have mentioned it above.
Additionally, I am able to replicate the behaviour on 2 machines so I am not discounting the conclusion that API 16 itself has issues with 320x320 etc and the device has custom extension to address this. I have revised the question to reflect this.

Comment: @siddesh: This may well be the case and it would be interesting to hear your reasons for this.